# Missing header at top of page?

Tags: bug

In other SE 2.0 sites, I get a short header in between the StackExchange link on the left and the search box on the right.  It includes account information and a link to meta (also review, chat, help).  I'm not seeing this on MO - should it be there?

I've added a screenshot below.  I'm definitely logged in (for example, I can see edit my account information on my user page).

[image: screenshot of header]

It shouldn't be a browser issue, since other SE 2.0 sites work for me.  The only potentially non-standard thing I did was to recover my account with a SE login and then replace it with another OpenID and delete the SE login.  (Maybe that screwed it up?)

Comment: hmmm ... I have all those links in my header.

Comment: Post a screenshot please?

Comment: @Shog9: Just added one.

Comment: That's weird!! Have you tried hard refresh (or maybe even using a private browsing mode)?

Comment: @HenryCohn do you have some sort of adblock or user extensions?  We definitely never render an empty header from the server, so this is happening client-side.  Is it possible you have a user script that expects the SE 1.0 HTML and isn't happy at the moment?

Comment: No luck with hard refresh or private browsing, and I'm not running any user scripts myself.  However, tracking protection sounded pretty compelling: maybe the reason my browser is fine with other SE 2.0 sites and with MO 1.0 but not MO 2.0 is because it's filtering out certain things from stackexchange.com when it visits mathoverflow.net.  However, it didn't help.  When I disabled it some ads came back on other sites, but a hard refresh left MO unchanged, so I'm still puzzled.  Oh well, it's not a big deal.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Henry, I had a similar problem. I was using a plugin which loaded only images belonging to the site's domain and therefore was blocking images which were coming from stackexchange.com domain. I modified its settings and it works fine for me.

Comment: Presumably this is now [tag:STATUS-NO-LONGER-RELEVANT]?

Comment: @TRiG: Yes, thanks!